# I'm getting an error using Gettext in Android Studio

Tags: android

When using Gettext in Android Studio, I'm getting an error.
How do I fix this?

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView resultat;
    private EditText input_number1, input_number2;
    private Button buttonadd;
    private View add_button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        resultat = findViewById(R.id.resultat);
        input_number1 = findViewById(R.id.input_number1);
        input_number2 = findViewById(R.id.input_number2);
        buttonadd = findViewById(R.id.buttonadd);

        add_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                float num1 = Float.parseFloat(input_number1, getText().toString());
                float num2 = Float.parseFloat(input_number2, getText().toString());
                float res = num1 +  num2;
                resultat.setText(String.valueOf(res));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

My English is very bad, I'm using google translate

Answer (score 4):

Update these two lines

```
float num1 = Float.parseFloat(input_number1.getText().toString());
float num2 = Float.parseFloat(input_number2.getText().toString());
```

you were adding space with **comma** separation that was the error.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know `Float.parseFloat` only takes one parameter, and that should be a string,
you are passing two parameters, you have mistaken **'.'** with **','** and thats why you have a problem.

```
        float num1 = Float.parseFloat(input_number1, getText().toString());
```

and be aware that `getText().toString()` doesn't work as a standalone, it should always be called after a textView or EditText or something.
like this:

```
input_number1.getText().toString()
```